# Which Signature to use in spring's controller methods

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload

There are lots of possible signature while defining Spring's Controller method. I'm confused which one should i use and in which circumstances.
For example, I have below scenario.
I have to upload a file to server i have written a form for that
Below is HTML

```
<form action="uploadimage?id=${pencil.id}" method="post">
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="color:maroon;font-weight:bold;">Change/Upload Image</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="image" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="upload" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="pencilid" value="${pencil.id}" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

For this I'm writing controller method. While using @ModelAttribute it throws exception saying can't instantiate bean MaltipartFile as its an Interface and while using @RequestParam it returns 400 error code

using @requestParam

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadimage",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView uploadImage(@RequestParam ("pencilid") String id,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
{
    System.out.println("In Controller");
    Pencil pencil=null;
    PencilService pencilService=ServiceFactory.getPencilService();
    pencil=pencilService.getPencil(Integer.parseInt(id));
    ModelAndView model= new ModelAndView("pencilview","pencil",pencil);
    model.addObject("id",id);
    //MultipartFile file=(MultipartFile)param.get("image");
    System.out.println(file.getName());
    return model;
}
```

Using @ModelAttribute

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadimage",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView uploadImage(@ModelAttribute ("pencilid") String id,@ModelAttribute("file") MultipartFile file)
{
    System.out.println("In Controller");
    Pencil pencil=null;
    PencilService pencilService=ServiceFactory.getPencilService();
    pencil=pencilService.getPencil(Integer.parseInt(id));
    ModelAndView model= new ModelAndView("pencilview","pencil",pencil);
    model.addObject("id",id);
    //MultipartFile file=(MultipartFile)param.get("image");
    System.out.println(file.getName());
    return model;
}
```

Kindly let me know where i'm mistaking
in my Sping-servlet.xml i have defined multipartResolver as

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

     <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />

</bean>
```

Let me know if anything else is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your form should have an attribute enctype  like the following :

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

if you are uploading file , you Use the `@RequestParam` for your file and for the other form fields that you have , like the following :

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){

    }
```

in this example that is from the spring [documentation](http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) , the `handleFileUpload` takes two parameters , the first is a normal `String name` , that is a normal field , the second is a `file MultipartFile` that is the file you want to upload .

Hope that Helps .

Comment: My question is not just about uploading file. I need to know in which case i should use modelattribute and when requestparam