# Passing parameters from jsp to Spring Controller method

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working in a Spring MVC application which uses Hibernate.

In the JSP page I have a function which lists the values stored in the database(currently all the value).

I have written a method, where the list is only limited to an ID passed in the JSP file. I got the HQL query working right, so I know it is retrieving data based upon the ID as a parameter.

Now, I would like to use this method in the controller. For that I have to pass a parameter of ID to the list, so in the controller side, the function is called which will retrieve list based upon that ID.

Unfortunately I don't know how to pass parameters from a JSP file.

JSP File :

```
  <c:url var="addAction" value="/note/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="notices">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty notices.notetext}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="noticesid">
                        <spring:message text="noticesid"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="noticesid" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="noticesid" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="notetext">
                    <spring:message text="notetext"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="notetext"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="notetag" >
                    <spring:message text="notetag"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="notetag"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="notecolor">
                    <spring:message text="notecolor"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="notecolor" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="canvasid">
                    <spring:message text="canvasid"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="canvasid" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="sectionid">
                    <spring:message text="sectionid"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="sectionid"  />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="canvasnName">
                    <spring:message text="canvasnName"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="canvasnName"  />
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <c:if test="${!empty notices.noticesid}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Edit note"/>" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty notices.notetext}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add note"/>" />
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<br>
<h3>Notes List</h3>

<c:url var="listAction" value="/note/list/2323" ></c:url>
<c:if test="${!empty notices.noticesid}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">Notes ID</th>
            <th width="120">Notes text</th>
            <th width="120">Note Tag</th>
            <th width="120">Note color</th>
            <th width="120">Note section</th>
            <th width="120">Canvas id</th>
            <th width="120">Canvas name</th>
            <th width="120">Other id</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listNotes}" var="notices">
            <tr>
                <td>${notices.noticesid}</td>
                <td>${notices.notetext}</td>
                <td>${notices.notetag}</td>
                <td>${notices.notecolor}</td>
                <td>${notices.sectionid}</td>
                <td>${notices.canvasid}</td>
                <td>${notices.canvasnName}</td>
                <td>${notices.personid}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/editnote/${notices.noticesid}' />" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/removenote/${notices.noticesid}' />" >Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

Controller file with list function :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/note/list/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listNotes(@PathVariable int id,Model model) {
        Person person = personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        this.setSectionid(id);
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
       model.addAttribute("listNotes",this.notesService.listNotesBySectionId(id,person));
        return "note";
    }

@RequestMapping(value= "/note/add")
    public String addNote(@ModelAttribute("notices") Notes p,Model model) {
        Person person = personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        model.addAttribute("listNotes",this.notesService.listNotes());

        int id = getSectionid();
        System.out.println("Section id is"+id);
         model.addAttribute("listNotes",this.notesService.listNotesBySectionId(id,person));
        this.notesService.addNote(p, person);
        return "note";
    }
```

I tried looking up the net, but I don't know what it is called that I am looking for, so having a hard time. Any help would be good. Thank you.

Comment: please explain what you are trying to do in a clear way

Comment: @SanKrish : I have revised the question, kindly have a look.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the `id` from the jsp to controller ?

Comment: @SanKrish Yes. So I can use function I have written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your controller method should be like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = " /<your mapping>/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String listNotes(@PathVariable("id")int id,Model model) {
    Person person = personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
    int id = 2323;  // Currently passing static values for testing
    model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
    model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
    model.addAttribute("listNotes",this.notesService.listNotesBySectionId(id,person));
    return "note";
}
```

Use the `id` in your code, call the controller method from your JSP as:

```
/{your mapping}/{your id}
```

**UPDATE:**

Change your jsp code to:

```html
<c:forEach items="${listNotes}" var="notices" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td>${notices.noticesid}</td>
        <td>${notices.notetext}</td>
        <td>${notices.notetag}</td>
        <td>${notices.notecolor}</td>
        <td>${notices.sectionid}</td>
        <td>${notices.canvasid}</td>
        <td>${notices.canvasnName}</td>
        <td>${notices.personid}</td>
        <td><a href="<c:url value='/editnote/${listNotes[status.index].noticesid}' />" >Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="<c:url value='/removenote/${listNotes[status.index].noticesid}' />" >Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Seems like your method is going to work. Just one thing. How can i extract the @PathVariable value and assign to int id(currently set to 2323).

Comment: Change the data type of id to int. Modified my answer

Comment: Thanks. Can you look at the added JSP and Controller, the value of id always stays at zero.

Comment: irritating when you put so much effort into an answer for it not to be accepted.  +1

Answer (score 8):

Use the [@RequestParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) to pass a parameter to the controller handler method. 
In the jsp your form should have an input field with `name = "id"` like the following:

```
<input type="text" name="id" />
<input type="submit" />
```

Then in your controller, your handler method should be like the following:

```
@RequestMapping("listNotes")
public String listNotes(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
    Person person = personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
    model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
    model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
    model.addAttribute("listNotes", this.notesService.listNotesBySectionId(id, person));
    return "note";
}
```

Please also refer to these answers and tutorial:

- [Stackoverflow :: How take the parameter value of a GET HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13442732/957654)
- [Stackoverflow :: Which Signature to use in spring's controller methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26212929/957654)
- [Tutorial :: Spring MVC Annotations](http://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-mvc-requestmapping-annotation-example-with-controller-methods-headers-params-requestparam-pathvariable)

Comment: Can you have a look at the modified JSP and controller, somehow the id in controller always stays at zero.

Comment: you mean after using @requestParam ?

Comment: Yes. And in JSP I tried to use static value right now, like /note/list/2323. Still it stays at zero.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. The id remains static, hardcoded by developer. I don't want the user to click on the submit button. Can you check the updated JSP page.

Comment: what do you want exactly ?

Comment: The developer uses in JSP page something like this /note/list/2323, this '2323' is passed in list function and values with id 2323 are displayed. But the user has no control over it. That's more important.