# how to pass param from jsp to spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My spring mvc controller has a method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView search(@RequestParam("cn") String cn) {
    //do stuff
    return mav;
}
```

And I have a JSP page, where I'd like to send the value of the string cn:

```
<html>
 <head><title>Search Entry</title></head>
 <body>
  <h3>Search entry</h3>
  <a href="search"><input type="text" name="cn" value="search">
   <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure the jsp has something wrong, now the status message says:

"Request method 'GET' not supported".

If I delete method = RequestMethod.POST it says:

"Required String parameter 'cn' is not present; description: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"

Comment: Why not use pathvariable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameters from JSP to Controller in Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590036/passing-parameters-from-jsp-to-controller-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: How do you think `<input>` works?

Answer (score 3):

I can see that your are using Spring annotations so what you need to do is to modify your JSP to have a form instead of a link like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>Search Entry</title></head>
<body>
<h3>Search entry</h3>
<form action="search" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="cn" value="search">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want a GET method to work you need to modify your controller's method to accept GET and change your JSP like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>Search Entry</title></head>
<body>
<h3>Search entry</h3>
  <a href="search?cn=search">
     Search
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want your parameter to be not mandatory you can modify your [@RequestParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation like this:

```
@RequestParam(value = "cn", required = false) String cn
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to Define `action="search"`inside form tag that should be work

Answer (score -2):

Change your HTML :

```
<html>
<head><title>Search Entry</title></head>
<body>
<h3>Search entry</h3>
<a href="search"><input type="text" name="cn" value="search" action="search">
 <button type="submit">Search</button>
</a>
</body>
 </html>
```

or else follow this link:

- [Passing parameters from jsp to Spring Controller method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652679/passing-parameters-from-jsp-to-spring-controller-method)
- [Passing parameters from JSP to Controller in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590036/passing-parameters-from-jsp-to-controller-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: still: Required String parameter 'cn' is not present

Comment: please check my updated blog i have attached some useful link as well . hope it help

Comment: What do you think your changes will do? Why do you think so? What is the relevance of the links you've posted? If you think this is a duplicate, vote to close as such.

Comment: Why do you think `<input>` has an attribute named `action`?

Comment: What do you think a `<button>` will do inside an `<a>` anchor?